# Class<? extends T> usage

Tags: java

I want to know what is the usage of having such syntax. I have written a simple program as below,

```
public class Sample{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<? extends Collection> someCollectionClass = someMethod();
    }

    public static ArrayList someMethod() {
        return new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

Why it shows compilation error as,

```
- Collection is a raw type. References to generic type Collection<E> should be 
 parameterized
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to Class<? extends Collection>
```

In here does that Class expect a class (Its actually the object that it accept know, Is it?) which does extends the Collection. So whats wrong with ArrayList?

Also is it a valid if syntax if i declare something as `Class<? extends T>`

Comment: You can declare something as `Class<? extends T>`, but it doesn't refer to any Object in Java, that's what the class `Object` is for. Look here for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html, but `Class` refers to the actual implementation and details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error message stems from the type parameter in your declaration:

```
Class<? extends Collection> someCollectionClass = someMethod();
```

The type `Collection` is what is called a "raw type" in Java, because the interface `Collection` takes a type parameter, but none is given in the declaration. The same applies to the unadorned use of `ArrayList`.

However, The declaration doesn't actually do what I guess you think it does... You actually declare a variable named `someCollectionClass`, to which you can assign instances of type `Class<? extends Collection>`, i.e., (reflection) class descriptors (of a particular type). The second error message is the compiler complaining about that: an instance of type `ArrayList` (returned by `someMethod`) cannot be assigned to a variable, whose type is declared as "allow only instances of `Class<...>` (which is a special Java run-time type describing classes).

```
Collection someCollection = someMethod();
```

Comment: what is the practical usage of such syntax please? Class<? extends Collection> ?

Answer (score 5):

Because `ArrayList` is not a `Class`.  Perhaps you mean `someMethod().getClass()`?

Answer (score 0):

someMethod is returning an instance of type List, you are trying to assign it to a variable which is expecting the Collection class not an instance.  The following code should work.

```
Collection someCollectionClass = someMethod();
```